# C# winforms Why messageboxes dont work with IF for DataReader

Tags: c#, winforms

I just write my very first program in C#(winforms) VS2019.
So far, so good, but i stuck here.
In code below i try to

1. Get data from datapicker named dtDataClear, convert it do string for sql select
2. Check if textbox 'tbMagClear' is empty
3. If empty - run delete command for sql base limited by date from dtDataClear
4. But if not empty i still have two actions to do
5. If string in tbMagClear exist in table3 get his id and use it for where in delete command
6. If string do not exist - throw message

Now, i have 2 main problems

first - i tried to check, if select for Table3 actually works,
but testing messagebox with id dont appear  (if it will work, message will be change to sql delete)

second - messagebox which is supposed to throw 'Not found' if string dont exist in database gets error in VS:
Cannot assign to 'Show' because it is a 'method group'

What is wrong here?

```
private void btMagClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = $@"Data Source={tbSerwer.Text}; Initial Catalog={tbBaza.Text};User ID={tbLogin.Text}; Password={tbPassword.Text}";

    try
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection;
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        string DataMa = dtDataClear.Value.Year.ToString() + dtDataClear.Value.Month.ToString() + dtDataClear.Value.Day.ToString();


        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbMagClear.Text))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($@"delete from TABLE where CODE not in (select CODE from TABLE2 where DATA > '{DataMa}' )", sqlConnection);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommandSelect;
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader;
            string sqlSelect = "";


            sqlSelect = $@"select id from TABLE3 where CODE2 = '{tbMagClear.Text}'";

            sqlCommandSelect = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);

            sqlDataReader = sqlCommandSelect.ExecuteReader();
            int MagID = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);


            if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(MagID));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show = ("Not Found");
            }

            sqlDataReader.Close();
            sqlCommandSelect.Dispose();

        }

        // MessageBox.Show(DataMa);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow, but your second issue is easy enough. `Show` is a method so you need to call it by adding parentheses: `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: Change that one line like this:  `MessageBox.Show("Not Found");`

Comment: `catch (Exception)  { }` Don't just discard exceptions. They can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: You must dispose `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`. Wrap them in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got this
Thank You all - second problem was indeed an actual blindness of me

As for problem with DataReader, reading an exception was brilliant ;)
'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present'
so this code works:

```
sqlCommandSelect = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);
sqlDataReader = sqlCommandSelect.ExecuteReader();
                  
           if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
            {

               while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                        {
                         MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0)));

                        }
                    }
            else
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
                    }
```